# Wordpress : Custom Url Tag

Tags: wordpress, url, tags, directory

I have a question. 
I want use the system of tag without the word `tag`.

Example : `http://xxxxxxxxx.com/tag/Matt` (will display all posts with tag Matt)
I want the same with `http://xxxxxxxxx.com/**people**/Matt` (will display too all posts with tag Matt)

Help, please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is :

> **Custom Taxonomies**

Answer (score 0):

If you want for 2 different URLs to resolve to the same page, then you can add the following your .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteRule ^people/(.*)$ tag/$1 [L,NC]
```

With this, you can then view:

```
http://domain.com/tag/matt
http://domain.com/people/matt
```

which will display the same page. Problems are content duplication and when you visit `/people/new-york`, it will show all posts tagged new-york even though it is not a person.

My suggestion then is to use this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^people/(.*)$ tag/people:$1 [L,NC]
```

Which makes your URLs resolve to something like: http://domain.com/tag/people:matt, which means, you can just tag posts as `people:matt`, and/or `people:arvin`, thus adding metadata to the tags.